# How many instances of a task scheduler should there be?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to make the correct use of a task scheduler, namely `IOTaskScheduler`. I have an app that crawls web pages and for each request (which is a task) I am generating a new `IOTaskScheduler`. Rather, should I have only one instance of `IOTaskScheduler` and pass that to all web requests (tasks)?

Alternatively in which cases would it be preferred to generate separate task schedulers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the question: For this `TaskScheduler` you need to share an instance so that many tasks can be multiplexed onto the few threads that this scheduler provides.

What you should do instead: You should not use this task scheduler at all. It does nothing special to make IO faster. Use a normal fixed concurrency scheduler that uses normal .NET threads.

> Alternatively in which cases would it be preferred to generate separate task schedulers?

I don't know of any. Schedulers are meant to multiplex many tasks to few threads. Registering a single task with each scheduler limits what the scheduler can intelligently do.

For some schedulers it does not matter. For example for a scheduler that puts each task onto a new thread.

Comment: Thank you for the brilliant answer, with regard to your recommendation of using a fixed concurrency scheduler, would the IOCompletionPortTaskScheduler qualify which requires you specify a fixed number of threads that are available?

Comment: I thought you were using that. You can use it if you want. My thinking is just that it does not provide a benefit above the other more simple schedulers in the ParallelExtensions. What about LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler? The ParallelExtensions have bugs (which found out). Use the simplest class that works. The IOCP scheduler uses unsafe code for example. You might not want to have this in production.

Comment: Not at the moment, I'm currently using IOTaskScheduler. However thank you for your comments and advice, I shall take it on board. Many thanks again.